# Create words in array JS

Tags: javascript

Hello I am retrieving text with ajax and have used body.textContent to get the text from a page. This was successful and I get the text however I then need to manipulate it but when I try to loop through it and compare some items in it it turns out for example the word 'hello' is actually taken as 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o'. Is there a way to get this as the full word instead??
This is what gets the text:

```
var getT=body.textContent;
//i then loop through it using
for(var i=; i<getT.length; i++){
    if(getT[i]==curr){...
```

Comment: So you're asking how to convert a string of text to a list of individual words? Did you do a search for that topic? Pretty sure it's been covered exhaustively.

Comment: Are you just looking for `getT.split(" ")`?

Comment: no i have the string of words I am just unsure of how to get the whole word instead of its individual letters I cant find anything anywhere

Comment: @newbie: How is that different? You want to loop over a list of words, right? If not, then please explain what you need more clearly.

Comment: I think split will give you exactly what you want: an array with words. You can then loop through the array and execute code for each word in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), and use a space as a delimiter.